# How to unspiderfy the markers on page load when using OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier on Gmap

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I wish to unspiderfy the markers that are on same geo-points on GMAP
on page load when using OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier instead of mouse click event.
The reason being the map displays on TV which has no click events.

Below is the code i worked:

```
<script> 

    function initialize() {
  var gm=google.maps;
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(20.5937, 78.9629);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  var oms = new OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier(map); 
  var iw = new gm.InfoWindow();
  oms.addListener('click', function(marker, event) {
    iw.setContent(marker.desc);
    iw.open(map, marker);
  });
  oms.addListener('spiderfy', function(markers) {
    iw.close();
  });

  var locations = ["Delhi, Mumbai", "Ahemdabad","Bengluru"]

  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i ++) {
    var title_i = "title " + i;
    var desc_i = "desc " + i;
    var loc = new gm.LatLng(20.5937, 78.9629);
    var marker = new gm.Marker({
      position: loc,
      title: title_i,
      map: map
    });
    marker.desc = desc_i;
    oms.addMarker(marker);  
  } 
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
```

Please help!
Thanks.

Comment: Could you please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and add it to your question?

Comment: @lavor- thanks for it. I have updated with the code i am using.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a group of markers using the `markersNearAnyOtherMarker()` function of the Overlapping Marker Spiderfier, retrieve the last marker of the array and trigger a click event on the last marker to open your group of markers programmatically. Relevant part of code is

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function(ev){
    var mm = oms.markersNearAnyOtherMarker();

    var m1 = mm.pop();
    google.maps.event.trigger(m1, 'click', {
        stop: null, 
        latLng: myLatlng
    });
});
```

Have a look at following sample and run it

```js
var map;
function initMap() {
  var gm=google.maps;
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(20.5937, 78.9629);
  var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 4,
      center: myLatlng
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  var oms = new OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier(map); 
  var iw = new gm.InfoWindow();
  oms.addListener('click', function(marker, event) {
      iw.setContent(marker.desc);
      iw.open(map, marker);
  });
  oms.addListener('spiderfy', function(markers) {
      iw.close();
  });

  var locations = ["Delhi, Mumbai", "Ahemdabad","Bengluru"]

  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i ++) {
    var title_i = "title " + i;
    var desc_i = "desc " + i;
    var loc = new gm.LatLng(20.5937, 78.9629);
    var marker = new gm.Marker({
      position: loc,
      title: title_i,
      map: map
    });
    marker.desc = desc_i;
    oms.addMarker(marker);  
  }

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function(ev){
    var mm = oms.markersNearAnyOtherMarker();

    var m1 = mm.pop();
    google.maps.event.trigger(m1, 'click', {
      stop: null, 
      latLng: myLatlng
    });
  });

}
```

```css
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDztlrk_3CnzGHo7CFvLFqE_2bUKEq1JEU&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier/1.0.3/oms.min.js"></script>
```

This example is also available at jsbin: http://jsbin.com/sayude/edit?html,output

I hope this helps!